# Generating a heat map using 3D data in matplotlib

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, visualization

I have a function `returnValuesAtTime` that returns three lists-`x_vals`,`y_vals` and `swe_vals`. All three lists are of the same length and each element in `swe_vals` corresponds to a `x-value` from `x_vals` and a `y-value` from `y_vals`. I wish to generate a heatmap with a legend that uses the `(x,y)` coordinates and the `swe_vals` as the intensity.

I wrote the following code:

```
def plotValuesAtTimeMap(t):
    x_vals,y_vals,swe_vals=returnValuesAtTime(t)
    x_points=len(x_vals)
    y_points=len(y_vals)
    xx=np.linspace(x_vals[0],x_vals[-1],x_points)
    yy=np.linspace(y_vals[0],y_vals[-1],y_points)
    fig,ax=plt.subplots()
    im=ax.pcolormesh(xx,yy,z)
    fig.colorbar(im)
    ax.axis('tight')
    plt.show()
```

Once the three lists are obtained using `returnValuesAtTime(t)`, I take the lengths of `x_vals` and `y_vals`. I then use these to generate the spacing for x and y-directions, with the limits being the first and last elements of `x_vals` and `y_vals`. I then try to generate the `colormesh`. But this gives me an empty `colormesh` with no values.

What might be going wrong? Will using a 3D `numpy` array instead of the three lists solve the problem?

The first 10 elements of each of the lists are:

```
x_vals[0:10]

[439936.86573189893,
 439936.86573189893,
 439936.86573189893,
 439936.86573189893,
 439936.86573189893,
 439936.86573189893,
 439936.86573189893,
 439936.86573189893,
 439936.86573189893,
 439936.86573189893]

y_vals[0:10]

[4514018.2797159087,
 4513898.2797159087,
 4513778.2797159087,
 4513658.2797159087,
 4513538.2797159087,
 4513418.2797159087,
 4513298.2797159087,
 4513178.2797159087,
 4513058.2797159087,
 4512938.2797159087]

swe_vals[0:10]

[2.7520323,
 2.7456229,
 2.7456021,
 2.745455,
 2.7478349,
 2.7445269,
 2.7484877,
 2.7524617,
 2.75491,
 2.7509627]
```

**Edit**:

I have added a scatter plot showing the (x,y) grid range below:

[image]

The x and y values are in lists, each 6804 in length. Each (x,y) point has a corresponding z-value in a separate list, which is also 6804 in length. To clarify what I hope to achieve, I want to generate a heatmap like plot with the magnitude of z-axis represented by the color of each grid on the plot. Something like what's shown below:

[image]

In the example plot, all z-values are the same. So the color is same across the entire grid space.

**Edited with new resultant plot (based on member CT Zhu's suggestions):**

[image]

Comment: Is safe to assume that  your `x_vals` and `y_vals` not evenly distributed, such as `1,2,3,4,....`? Mostly likely yes as you have a line of `xx=np.linspace(x_vals[0],x_vals[-1],x_points)`?

Comment: @CTZhu They are evenly distributed, with the first three elements of x_vals being [ 439936.8657319,  440056.8657319,  440176.8657319] and the first three elements of y_vals being [ 4514018.27971591,  4513898.27971591,  4513778.27971591]. Every element in x_vals is 120.0 more than the previous, and every element in y_vals is 120.0 less than the previous.

Comment: I see, like one come out of `meshgrid`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks like if reshape `x`, `y`, `z` to square matrix, you can do a `contourf` plot:

```
In [7]:X
Out[7]:
array([[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
       [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
       [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
       [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
       [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
       [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
       [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
       [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
       [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
       [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]])

In [8]:Y
Out[8]:
array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
       [2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2],
       [3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3],
       [4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4],
       [5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5],
       [6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6],
       [7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7],
       [8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8],
       [9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9]])

plt.contourf(X,Y,np.random.random((10,10))) #reshape Z too!
plt.colorbar()
```

[image]

Comment: Is there a specific difference between a matrix and an array? I have another function that returns a 3D numpy array containing the x-coordinate, y-coordinate and the z-value (swe_vals).

The function is:

def createArray(t):
     x_vals,y_vals,swe_vals=returnValuesAtTime(t)
     swe_array=np.array([x_vals,y_vals,swe_vals],np.float32)
     return swe_array
.
Is there a way I can convert this to matrix and generate the graph?

Comment: Each of my lists (x,y and z) has 6804 values. Is it possible to convert this to a square matrix? I have tried multiple methods, but none of them seem to work.

Comment: If you make a scatter plot of `x` and `y`, does it appears to be an evenly distributed square grid? 6804 is a little strange and won't become a square matrix, 82*83=8606

Comment: I have added some example plots in my question edits. 6804 does not become a square matrix.

Comment: It looks like your grid is indeed 84*81, can you verify it by `len(set(x_vals))`? If the grid is 84*81, you can make the heatmap as described, but reshape your data in to `(84,81)` rather then a square matrix.

Comment: Thanks, that worked! But the y-axis doesn't seem to have been fully plotted. The maximum value on my y-axis should be about 4514018.28, but the plot only shows till 10000, and displays +4.50E-6 at the top. Do you know why this is happening? I have updated the new plot in the edits to my question.

Comment: That should be the normal behavior when the numbers are large. But I think it means your largest Y values are somewhere around 10000*4.5*1000000.