# Generating Discrete Heatmap from 3D Data in Matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, heatmap

So I want to do something like this:

[Generating a heat map using 3D data in matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22872061/generating-a-heat-map-using-3d-data-in-matplotlib)

But I don't want my color axis to be continuous.

---

My input data is of the form:

```
x = [0, 0, 0, ... , 20, 20, 20, ..., 39, 39, 39]
y = [0, 1, 2, ..., 0, 1, 2... , 37, 38, 39]
z = [0, 1, 0, ..., 1, 1, 0, ..., 1, 0 ,0]
```

In other words, my  z value is either a 0, or a 1, and never goes in-between.

I try:

```
 import numpy
 import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

 #===Load Data===#
 data = numpy.loadtxt("class_map.dat");

 #===Get Array Sizes===#
 max_x_size = int(numpy.sqrt(len(data[:,0])));
 max_y_size = int(numpy.sqrt(len(data[:,1])));

 #===Reshape Into Square Grid===#
 x = data[:,0]; xx = numpy.reshape(x, (max_x_size, max_x_size));
 y = data[:,1]; yy = numpy.reshape(y, (max_y_size, max_y_size));
 z = data[:,2]; zz = numpy.reshape(z, (max_x_size, max_y_size));

 #===Plot===#
 plt.subplot(111)
 plt.contourf(xx,yy,zz)
 plt.colorbar()
 plt.show();
```

But what I get is:

[image: Result]

It looks like contourf is giving me a continuous function. I want it to simply display the values that are already in the z-variable, rather than fitting a function to it. How can I do this?

Edit: Also, I would like to have the discrete values (0 or 1) on a gray scale, if possible.

Answer (score 0):

You may use the `levels` argument to [contour](http://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.contourf.html), e.g `levels=[0,0.5,1]`.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#===Load Data===#
x,y  = np.meshgrid(np.arange(20),np.arange(20) )
data = np.random.randint(0,2, size=(20,20))

#===Plot===#
plt.subplot(111)
plt.contourf(x,y,data, levels=[0,0.5,1])
plt.colorbar()
plt.show()
```

[image]

Another option may be to use `imshow()`

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#===Load Data===#
x,y  = np.meshgrid(np.arange(20),np.arange(20) )
data = np.random.randint(0,2, size=(20,20))

#===Plot===#
plt.subplot(111)
plt.imshow(data, interpolation="None")
plt.colorbar()
plt.show()
```

[image]