# Generate a heatmap in Python with xyz dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, heatmap

I have x,y,z data stored in a pandas dataframe from which I would like to generate a 2D heatmap (depth plot).

```
df= pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100,size=(100, 3)), columns=list('XYZ'))
```

I am uncertain of how to do this with matplotlib. [This example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22872061/generating-a-heat-map-using-3d-data-in-matplotlib) suggests converting to a numpy array and creating a contourf plot. Is there a way to plot directly from pandas? If not, how would I reshape the dataframe into a 2d numpy array?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, dataframes are numpy arrays. They are just extended to have a lot of other nice features. So there is no need to "convert" anything here.

Second, plotting random values as a heatmap is not going to work. You will either need to have meaningful coordinates or you will need to have meaningful z-values.

If everything is random the only thing you can do, which would formally work (but not give a meaningful result) is to use a `tripcolor` or a `tricontourf` plot.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df= pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100,size=(100, 3)), columns=list('XYZ'))

fig, (ax, ax2)=plt.subplots(ncols=2)
ax.set_title("tripcolor")
ax.tripcolor(df["X"], df["Y"], df["Z"])
ax2.set_title("tricontour")
ax2.tricontourf(df["X"], df["Y"], df["Z"])

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks - my data are not random, I was just generating random data to save explaining / importing real data. My datapoints are correlated with their neighbours, hence i expect there to be distinct 'peaks' and 'troughs' on the heatmap

Comment: My answer can only be as good as the question and it cannot go beyond what is asked. But you may feel free to update your question.

Comment: It's a very good answer, just thought it goes without saying that I'm creating fake data that mimics the structure of mine. Would be a pointless exercise otherwise.

Comment: My point is that it may depend on the actual data which solution is the best. So here I presented the best (possibly only) solution for random data. If your data is not random, there might be better solution - but I cannot provide you with those without knowing anything about the real data.